Kentico 13 Edit froala_style.min.css
what's the best way to edit/add froala_style.min.css?
I want to apply the stylings for my incline classes in the editor so that it's actually wysiwyg. I'm not sure if I need to do it in the CMS or the live site.
Thanks

will this fit your needs? https://docs.kentico.com/13/configuring-xperience/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-the-rich-text-editor-for-page-builder/customizing-the-rich-text-editor-toolbar  and maybe adding some plugins? https://docs.kentico.com/13/configuring-xperience/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-the-rich-text-editor-for-page-builder/implementing-rich-text-editor-plugins

Found the answer. Add the below to your config.js
 iframeStyleFiles: ['/styles/mystyles.min.css']

From the froala docs https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/#iframeStyleFiles
